# How can I change the tickLabel on a NumberAxis in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart and want to be able to change the label on the range axis from a number to something more meaningful for the domain I am in.  I only see options for customizing the look of the label and no way to override the content of the label based on the position of the tick.

Does anyone know how to override the text of the tickLabel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JFreeChart [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo2/BarChartDemo1.java) shows how to use the [`setStandardTickUnits()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setStandardTickUnits-org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnitSource-) method. [`NumberAxis`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html) has several handy static factories for this. To override the defaults, you can "create your own instance of [`TickUnits`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnits.html) and then pass it to the [`setStandardTickUnits()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setStandardTickUnits-org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnitSource-) method."

Addendum: The defaults mentioned above simply use a subclass of `java.text.Format`; you can supply your own for each `TickUnit` you `add()`. If this is inadequate, you can override [`valueToString()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnit.html#valueToString-double-) in your own concrete subclass of [`TickUnit`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnit.html) and use it to compose the required [`TickUnits`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnits.html).

Comment: Not as easy as I was hoping for, but this is great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I just found this while having the same problem. I solved it by using a [`SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html). [`SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html) can be added to a `XYPlot`.

```
SymbolAxis sa = new SymbolAxis("AxisLabel",
    new String[]{"Category1","Category2","Category3","..."});
chart.getPlot().setDomainAxis(sa);
```