# How could java.text.NumberFormat be used to add units?

Tags: java, jfreechart, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to go about formatting 1200 to 1.2k in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java)

When displaying a number I would like to automatically adjust the units to limit the size of numbers. For instance if working with meters and a number like 22000 then I would like to display 22 km, but if the number is 22 then I would just display 22 m.
It seems like `java.text.NumberFormat` could be extended to add units. If so, can you clarify how the api is used (I've [RTFM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)). If not, is there another java api you would suggest?

*Further context. I'm working within JFreeChart and was led to NumberFormat from its [API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setNumberFormatOverride%28java.text.NumberFormat%29)*

Comment: See also [`createStandardTickUnits()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#line.681) ff.

Comment: @trashgod can you elaborate on the tick units paradigm. I understand how to use them to specify the frequency of ticks, but not how to control the labels. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Suraj! Of the answers in the *dup of How to go about formatting* I'd like to point future folks to jzd's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java/4754692#4754692

Answer (score 1):

You can add the desired literals to the [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instances used by your custom [`TickUnits`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnits.html). The [`createStandardTickUnits()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#line.681) method is a reasonable model to follow. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365657/how-can-i-change-the-ticklabel-on-a-numberaxis-in-jfreechart/2366808#2366808).

Comment: I don't see an easy way to use @jzd's approach.

Comment: @mort adduced a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458824/jfreechart-polarplot-mathematical-orientation/3466681#3466681).