# Formatting Y-axis on JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a StackedXYAreaChart similar to the one below:

[image]

On the Y-axis, instead of the tick units shown (`2.5`, `5.0`, `7.5`, `10.0`, etc.), I have the following: `100,000`, `200,000`, `300,000`, `400,000`, etc. These represent Bytes, just like the one above. My question is: is there a way I could format these tick units such that they represent Kilobytes, i.e. `100`, `200`, `300`, `400`, etc. or even Megabytes, i.e. `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3`, `0.4`, etc.? I don't want to display 10 MB as `10,000,000` on the Y-axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static factory [`createStackedAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1142) instatiates a `NumberAxis` for the range. The `NumberAxis` method [`createStandardTickUnits()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#line.684) creates the standard tick units, which may serve as an example for creating your own units. In particular, "If you don't like these defaults, create your own instance of `TickUnits` and then pass it to the `setStandardTickUnits()` method." There's more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365657/how-can-i-change-the-ticklabel-on-a-numberaxis-in-jfreechart/2366808#2366808).

Comment: I subclassed `NumberTickUnit`, overwrote the `valueToString` method, used my own formatter in the `valueToString` method, and then added my custom tick unit to `TickUnits`; and it worked! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would of done a byte conversion, converting from

```
KB to MB=(KB/1024)
KB to TB=(KB/(1024*2))
KB to GB=(KB/(1024*3))
KB to PB=(KB/(1024*4))
```

Where the the NumberAxis should auto range depending on the value passed.