# How can i customize the domain's "ruler" in a Scatter plot (JFreeChart)?

Tags: java, jfreechart, scatter-plot

I have this scatter plot working nice, but I couldn't find how to acess the domain's ruler ( the number range at left, from 0.40 to 0.95) and change some things:

- Set a custom range instead of using my highest and lowest values from the provided dataset (set range to 0.00 to 1.00)
- Show only the highest and lowest values, hide the others (the desired 0.00 and 1.00 from item above)

Any information would help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: @trashgod: No, it's not. Nothing is said about customizing the ruler or hiding values

Comment: Maybe try `setRange()`, used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513), with custom tick units, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722234/230513).