# Y Axis is not displaying correct figure for Millions and Billions in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

While generating Bar Graph using JFreeChart, I am getting billions and Millions value in scientific numeric format, that is having less readability,

[image]

There is any way, so that I can get the value like using JfreeChart.

[image]

It has to be dynamic for Million, Billions for all value.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Haroldo_OK and @trashgod for you hint and finally I got the solution for the same and It's giving me the expected result.

```
final long MILLION = 1000000L;
    final long BILLION = 1000000000L;
    final long TRILLION = 1000000000000L;
    final long THOUSAND = 1000L;

    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new NumberFormat() {

        @Override
        public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {

            String temp =  number < THOUSAND ? String.valueOf(number) :
                number < MILLION ?  (int)(number / THOUSAND) + " K" :
                number < BILLION ?  (int)(number / MILLION) + " M" :
                number < TRILLION ? (int)(number / BILLION) + " B" : 
                (int)(number / TRILLION) + " T";
            return new StringBuffer(temp);
        }

        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {

            String temp =  number < THOUSAND ? String.valueOf(number) :
                number < MILLION ?  (int)(number / THOUSAND) + " K" :
                number < BILLION ?  (int)(number / MILLION) + " M" :
                number < TRILLION ? (int)(number / BILLION) + " B" : 
                (int)(number / TRILLION) + " T";
            return new StringBuffer(temp);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad you got it working; also consider making constants `static`, using `_` in numeric constants, and factoring out common code.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod for suggestion.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use invoke [`setNumberFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setNumberFormatOverride-java.text.NumberFormat-) on your plot's `NumberAxis`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33595830/230513). You'll need a custom [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), possibly using one of the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3263892/230513) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3758606/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create your own custom [TickUnits](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnits.html), as [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721768/formatting-y-axis-on-jfreechart) suggests.