# JFreechart with string and double

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jfreechart

I'm trying to make a JFreeChart XY-graph with an X-axis containing strings from a db and a Y-axis containing the corresponding double value.

I've looped through a dozen of examples from all over the internet but I am not able to find a working example.

Are there anyone who knows something that I can use?

Comment: More info about the "strings" on x-axis please. Real examples? How would you order them? etc

Comment: This sound more like a `CategoryDataset`, perhaps `JDBCCategoryDataset`.

Comment: In other words, how can you change the string values of the x-axis in a way that instead of showing numbers, you show your own text

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html) for this.

See:
[How can I change the tickLabel on a NumberAxis in JFreeChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365657/how-can-i-change-the-ticklabel-on-a-numberaxis-in-jfreechart)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will help you, just past the code in your IDE and run.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.DefaultCategoryDataset;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class BarChart {

    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        // row keys...
        String series1 = "First";
        String series2 = "Second";
        String series3 = "Third";
        // column keys...
        String category1 = "Category 1";
        String category2 = "Category 2";
        String category3 = "Category 3";
        String category4 = "Category 4";
        String category5 = "Category 5";
        // create the dataset...
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(1.0, series1, category1);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category2);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series1, category3);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category4);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category5);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category1);
        dataset.addValue(7.0, series2, category2);
        dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category3);
        dataset.addValue(8.0, series2, category4);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series2, category5);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series3, category1);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category2);
        dataset.addValue(2.0, series3, category3);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category4);
        dataset.addValue(6.0, series3, category5);
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\";
        BarChart bc = new BarChart();
        // create the chart...
        JFreeChart chart = bc.createChart(bc.createDataset());
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(path + "jfreechartimg.jpeg");
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, chart, 600, 400);
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
        } finally {
            try{out.close();}catch(Exception ignore){}
        }
        System.out.println("finished !");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a sample chart.
     *
     * @param dataset the dataset.
     *
     * @return The chart.
     */
    private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
        // create the chart...
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "Bar Chart Demo for Mr P.", // chart title
                "Category", // domain axis label
                "Value", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips?
                false // URLs?
                );
        // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...
        // set the background color for the chart...
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(255,255,91));
        // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        // set the range axis to display integers only...
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        // disable bar outlines...
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        // set up gradient paints for series...
        GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(161,29,33),
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(249,175,154));
        GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0,108,56),
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(119,193,88));
        GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(35,65,139),
                0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(185,219,243));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, gp1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, gp2);

        return chart;
    }
}
```

The output of the code:

[image]